# WPML best page selector with php

Tags: php, plugin-wpml

I have a multilingual website made with WPML.
I have php code to run across pages but I cannot uniquely target the page with `is_page(ID)` since the ID of the page changes across language domain.
I need to write the code to target the page for each language.
What is the best practice to target pages across language domain?

Comment: This would be specific to WPML. Since third party plugins are off topic here, I suggest checking their developer resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code returns the post ID in the current language.

```
$translated_post_id = apply_filters( 'wpml_object_id', $post_id, 'post' );
```

So, you can use `$translated_post_id` in `is_page`.

[Documentation](https://wpml.org/wpml-hook/wpml_object_id/).